# Java OutOfMemory Error

Tags: java, jvm, out-of-memory

I am seeing an OutOfMemory problem and I am not sure it is the PERM GEN area or the heap space. The error message does not say anything about which area ran out of memory.

Here is a partial stack trace:
The following is information that may be useful to the developer of BETWEENNESS: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method) at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:127) at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:143) at com..util.internal.ZipFiles.unzip(ZipFiles.java:91) 
I looked at the heap space just before it ran out of memory using the jmap -heap command:

```
 using thread-local object allocation.
 Parallel GC with 23 thread(s)

 Heap Configuration:
    MinHeapFreeRatio = 40
    MaxHeapFreeRatio = 70
    MaxHeapSize      = 31675383808 (30208.0MB)
    NewSize          = 1310720 (1.25MB)
    MaxNewSize       = 17592186044415 MB
    OldSize          = 5439488 (5.1875MB)
    NewRatio         = 2
    SurvivorRatio    = 8
    PermSize         = 21757952 (20.75MB)
    MaxPermSize      = 536870912 (512.0MB)

 Heap Usage:
 PS Young Generation
 Eden Space:
    capacity = 9762177024 (9309.9375MB)
    used     = 7286558512 (6949.003707885742MB)
    free     = 2475618512 (2360.933792114258MB)
    74.64071276403028% used
 From Space:
    capacity = 396230656 (377.875MB)
    used     = 340623360 (324.84375MB)
    free     = 55607296 (53.03125MB)
    85.96592788620576% used
 To Space:
    capacity = 398131200 (379.6875MB)
    used     = 0 (0.0MB)
    free     = 398131200 (379.6875MB)
    0.0% used
 PS Old Generation
    capacity = 1992163328 (1899.875MB)
    used     = 1455304512 (1387.8865356445312MB)
    free     = 536858816 (511.98846435546875MB)
    73.05146578825087% used
 PS Perm Generation
    capacity = 418578432 (399.1875MB)
    used     = 418567008 (399.1766052246094MB)
    free     = 11424 (0.010894775390625MB)
    99.99727076238844% used }
```

And also, I had supplied the following arguments to the JVM: -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/tmp/ but I do not see any heap.

My questions is why is the heap not being generated and how do I figure out which part of the JVm is getting full.

Thanks.

Comment: Here is the output from the jmap -heap command:

Comment: are you using a server such as glassfish?

Comment: no, I am not, its a java application I am running

Comment: Looks like PermGen is at 99.99% used, so try increasing that. Also dump the heap and use [Eclipse Memory Analyzer](https://www.eclipse.org/mat/) to figure out where the memory leak is. Your application memory is also blowing up.

Comment: 99.99% is the memory used of 400MB currently allocated. 500MB is the total capacity of the PERM GEN which makes it 80% of the total capacity used.

Answer (score 3):

Your provided information says, that your PermGen is 99% full. And your Heap is already 73% full. So increasing both would not be bad at all.

Further you could activate the garbage collector's logging with `-XX:+PrintGCDetails` to get detailed information on how your JVM is using memory. Additionally activate `-XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps` and `-XX:+PrintGCDateStamps`. `-Xloggc:$filename` sends the logs to a file, which you could easily analyze with something like [IMB PMAT tool](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/groups/service/html/communityview?communityUuid=22d56091-3a7b-4497-b36e-634b51838e11) or [GCViewer](https://github.com/chewiebug/GCViewer).

Additionally you should consider using [VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/) to monitor your application while running.

Besides:
A colleague of mine found a smart way to get a heapdump many times faster through gdb:

```
cat > /tmp/dodump <<EOF
gcore jvm.core
detach
quit
EOF
time gdb --batch --command=/tmp/dodump --pid=`pgrep java`
jmap -dump:format=b,file=jvm.hprof `which java` jvm.core
rm jvm.core
gzip -9 jvm.hprof
```

[Source](https://plus.google.com/u/0/105550606573805398703/posts)

Credits go fully to him.

Comment: I have tried jmap to analyze the running heap. But noting jumps out of ordinary. And also, 99% is the PERM GEN memory used which is allocated. But the allocated memory (399MB) has not reached the full capacity(500MB)

Answer (score 0):

According to stack trace, `OutOfMemoryError` happens inside `ZipFile.open()` native method. This means that the problem has nothing to do with Java Heap size nor with PermGen. It is likely related with ZIP cache which is malloc'ed or mmap'ed internally by JDK library.

Try adding `-Dsun.zip.disableMemoryMapping=true` JVM option to see if it helps.
How large is ZIP file being opened?